# WPF path animation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have created the following XAML

```
<Canvas Background="Gray" Margin="10">    
    <Ellipse x:Name="Node1" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="AliceBlue" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="136" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="Node2" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="AliceBlue" Canvas.Left="290" Canvas.Top="136" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="object" Width="10" Height="20" Fill="Black" Canvas.Left="43" Canvas.Top="125" />
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="50,145">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <LineSegment Point="100,100" />
                                    <LineSegment Point="250,100" />
                                    <LineSegment Point="300,145" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

As you can see, I have created 2 elliptical Nodes. A path connecting the two nodes and an object sitting at node 1. All I want to do here is to animate the object at node1 along the path towards node2.

**I am trying to do the animation using code** as I want the animation to happen on click of the node2. I have been struggling with DoubleAnimation, MatrixAnimation,storyboard..Very confusing. Please share you knowledge on how to achieve this. I am hoping the same code would work with curves and complex paths.

Answer (score 2):

You need `DoubleAnimationUsingPath` [(ref)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimationusingpath.aspx):

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:2" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="object">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M2,10 L52,-35 L202,-35 L252,10"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:2" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="object">
                <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M2,10 L52,-35 L202,-35 L252,10"/>
                </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Canvas Background="Gray" Margin="10">    
    <Ellipse x:Name="Node1" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="AliceBlue" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="136" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="Node2" Width="20" Height="20" Fill="AliceBlue" Canvas.Left="290" Canvas.Top="136" />
    <Ellipse x:Name="object" Width="10" Height="20" Fill="Black" Canvas.Left="43" Canvas.Top="125" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" MouseLeftButtonDown="object_MouseLeftButtonDown" >
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="50,145">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <LineSegment Point="100,100" />
                                    <LineSegment Point="250,100" />
                                    <LineSegment Point="300,145" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Then to invoke from code:

```
private void object_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Storyboard animation = this.TryFindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;
    animation.Begin();
}
```

---

[EDIT]
I think you're missing critical tool here: [Blend](http://blendinsider.com/). As for creating animation in code, if you look at XAML elements, think about them as serialized classes, which can be reflected in code, i.e.

```
    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    DoubleAnimationUsingPath ani_2 = new DoubleAnimationUsingPath();
    ani_2.Duration = new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2));

    PathGeometry pg = new PathGeometry();
    pg.Figures.Add(new PathFigure());

    ani_2.PathGeometry.AddGeometry(pg);
```

etc. It is however (IMAO) fairly painful to create those straight from code. It all really depends on the application.
Have a look [here](http://expression.microsoft.com/en-us/cc197141) for a starting point on Blend.

Comment: I tested using your methord and it works fine. But, still I dont understand a few things here. How you created the pathgeometry figures used in the animation? How would I create them via c# code? Say for example, I need to animate this object on a path that user has drawn, how would I convert the path to pathgeometry?

Comment: And why Canvas.GetLeft(@object) does'nt change after animation end? It would be also helpfull if you can provide a link to a good tutorial to understand these basic stuff.

Comment: But still..there should be a way to convert the Actual path {M50,145L100,100L250,100L300,145} to the animation path {M2,10 L52,-35 L202,-35 L252,10} right? If I can get that, then I can easily animate any object over any path without hardcoding it in XAML/Code right?

Comment: Not 100% sure on this one, but looking at the code seems that `Path.Data` contains `Path.Geometry`, maybe this could be used as `DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry`? I'll leave the research to you though ;)

Comment: tried that. But does'nt work. Path.Data gives the abosulte path geometry of the path. It corresponds to what we gave in XAML. But, the pathgeometry that we supplied to the animation offsets an amount to X,Y such that it starts from 0,0. In the above example, if we subtract 48 from X and 135 from Y we get the animation pathgeometry.

Comment: How about subtracting path's starting point from its coordinates? You may need to adjust `object`'s pivot (look how it behaves when starting to animate)

Comment: Yes. I am looking at PathGeometry transformations to achieve this.